# What's the name and model of this computer monitor?

Tags: crt-monitor, display, identify-this-computer

It's look like very old thing to me:

[image]

It's in Black and White display. As you can see, it has a socket on the top of it .

What's the name and model of this computer monitor?

Comment: Is that really a socket on top? Are you sure it's not a handle?

Comment: Generally you would find the name and model on the back, there may be an information plate. Can you post some more detailed pictures of different sides? Otherwise, the answer will just be "it's a [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube) monitor".

Comment: Open it up and look inside. There might be a plate with some information somewhere.

Comment: It could be a security monitor if not for the handle to make it portable.

Comment: What size is it? Could be one of those Philips 9 inch b&w CRTs. But like others have said, there's no telling without more details.

Comment: Definitely looks more like a CCTV monitor than a computer display.

Comment: If nothing else, you should at least give a reference of from where the picture is.

Answer (score 1):

Not a specific computer monitor at all, rather a generic B&W CRT screen. Setting looks also more like a CCTV, doesn't it, but I suspect it's from some game, so it's fantasy anyway.

That hole on the top isn't a socket, but a transport grip. Monitors meant to be integrated in some shelving (like usual for CCTV) got them embedded to save on space, allowing a denser package and reduce the need for cover/binds in shelving.